# How to make core-icon bigger inside a core-icon-button

Tags: polymer

https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-icon-button/demo.html

There is 14px padding left to make the icon bigger but I can't figure it out how to achieve for example a 30x30 icon instead of a 24x24 inside a default size core-icon-button.

When I change the padding and size it is not in the center anymore.

The closest I get is

```
core-icon-button::shadow core-icon {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

But this makes the complete button bigger not just the icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mix around with `transform`:

```
core-icon-button{
    transform: scale(2,2);
}
```

This will have an impact on image-quality though..